# SWReveal issue with navigation initiated by a UIAlert button selection

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a slide out menu implemented with SWReveal, it all works fine.

In the current Menu slide out I have the following options:

```
- Dashboard
- Items
- Buy Coins
- Logout
```

All navigation via the slide out menu work fine.

My issue is that I wish to programmatically call a certain view controller from a UIAlert based on an action.

So in my case, if the user tries to purchase an item but does not have enough money to buy, a `UIAlert` is displayed informing the user they do not have enough coins to purchase the item with a `Cancel` and `Buy Coins` options.

If the user click the `Cancel` button the UIAlert is dismissed, works fine

But if the user clicks the `Buy Coins` button I want the user to be taken to the Purchase View Controller directly and not view the slide out menu

Does anyone know how to do so?!

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with the following code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let sw = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
self.view.window?.rootViewController = sw

let destinationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryboardID") as! NameOfViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationController)
sw.pushFrontViewController(navigationController, animated: true)
```

That should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you:

```
let something = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RevealVC") as! SWRevealViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(something, animated: true)
```

Comment: This is only partial the answer, see my for the complete version